# How to stop the user sending post requests

Tags: php

```
    if($_POST)
    {

        if($this->session->userdata('just_sended'))
        {
            echo 'just sended';
            exit();

        }

        $newdata = array(
                   'just_sended'  => true

        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
    }
    else
    {
        $newdata = array(
                   'just_sended'  => false
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

    }
```

This is my code when the user send a post request, but i can't figure it out why it not works, the user spams the button "send" and in my database appears duplicates, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Redirect the user after a Post so the client cannot repost the data by pressing F5:

```
header("Location: /submitted.php");
echo 'just sended'; // will the user never see
exit();
```

**sumbitted.php:**

```
exit('just sended');
```

**Note:** You must not post any other data before the header line.

Comment: i don't know why but it doesn't redirect the user, just ignoring that, after checking if is just_sended it must redirect, looks like the server has no time to save the session, and the user is sending it again

Comment: Just check that you don't output something else before the call of `header()`, it's also possible that you have some empty lines before your `<?php` tag.

Comment: is in the first line of the php function that handles the request, before the <?php there are no spaces

Comment: Check if there is an UTF-8 / BOM header.

Comment: the user sends post request faster than the server adds the session checker i think...

Comment: there are no BOM, my php file is UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to accomplish this with the session, just query your database before inserting your information looking at the last post with some unique key (like their ip address) and if the information is the same, then don't insert.

Also, you could store a timestamp if you want to make sure it's just recent inserts you don't block from inserting.

Comment: this is more complicated, is really no other options rather than make queries db to fix this?

Comment: There are always other solutions to problems, this one is probably not as complicated as you think it is. And it doesn't need you to deal with trying to juggle session variables and header redirects.